# Loading multiple files in Javascript without promises

Tags: javascript

I have a file loader that is used in the following way:

```
const loader = new FileLoader();

loader.load(path1, data => { // onLoad function });
loader.load(path2, data => { // onLoad function });
```

I know I can wrap this loader in a promise and then use Promise.allSettled to process the results.

However, in my case I just need to call a function when all files are loaded, no need to check for failures, so I wrote the following code:

```
let toload = num_files;
for(let i = 0; i < num_files; i++) {
  loader.load(path[i], data => {
    // process data
    toload--;
    if(toload == 0) allDone(); 
  }
}
```

considering the async nature of loading, can this code fail and somehow miss `toload == 0` condition?

Comment: Yes, a common mistake: it fails when `num_files` is `0`. Just use `Promise.all`.

Comment: in this case num_files is never zero, what I meant is can toload be decremented twice before toload == 0 condition is checked like it would be the case with threads